# UIWebView disable double tap to make single tap responsed quicker

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview

I'm trying to build a html5 app with UIWebView. when click on a button of the html, it takes 300ms for the system to know it is a one tap but a double tap. Can I disable the double tap, so I can save the time to make my app response quicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Creating Fast Buttons for Mobile Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons?hl=de-DE) from Google.